# Github ssh key macOS Sierra

Tags: git, github, ssh, macos-sierra

I've been having problems with gitHub's SSH Key for Mac Sierra here: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

I've been able to follow the steps of

1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`
2. `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

However from this part onwards, nothing works

1. I do not understand what they mean by "modify your `~/.ssh/config` file " & the 
   Host *
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   UseKeychain yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
2. `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa` does not work on terminal either, as the results says 'no such file or directory'

I saved the key file to my Desktop folder when `ssh-keygen` prompted me for a location.

Answer (score 3):

When you did an `ssh-keygen`, you would have been prompted for the location to save the keys in. It is by default `~/.ssh/`. If you saved them somewhere else, you should try `locate id_rsa` and then do `ssh-add <path where id_rsa is>`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've actually saved it in my desktop initially and located the file it's in through terminal, however it doesn't work, leading to the problem stated above

Answer (score 2):

Move the key to `.ssh` where it belongs, and/or create a `.ssh/config` file and tell it where to look for the key.

If `.ssh` doesn't exist, you have to create it first, obviously.

```
# Create ~/.ssh if missing
if ! [ -d "$HOME"/.ssh ], then
    mkdir -p "$HOME"/.ssh
    # Make it private
    chmod 700 "$HOME"/.ssh
fi

# Move files from Desktop
# Assumes id_rsa* matches public and private key files,
# and no others
mv -i "$HOME"/Desktop/id_rsa* "$HOME"/.ssh

# Make them private, too
chmod go-rwx "$HOME"/.ssh/id_rsa*

# Create config file, if missing
test -e "$HOME"/.ssh/config ||
printf '%s\n' 'Host *' \
    '    AddKeysToAgent yes' \
    '    UseKeychain yes' \
    '    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa' >"$HOME"/.ssh/config
```

You can just copy/paste these commands to the Terminal, though putting them in a file like `/tmp/sshcommands` and running it with `bash /tmp/sshcommands` might be slightly less jarring.

Obviously, you should read up on these commands enough to understand at least roughly what's going on here. Probably the key realization is that `ssh` doesn't know you have a `Desktop` folder and would not want to look there for the key even if it knew. (You could change the final `IdentityFile` statement to actually change that, but really, at this point you are better off learning the standard practice.)

Comment: Add them each to your `.ssh/config` or use a key manager. Or just add your local primary public key to all of those as an authorized key.

Comment: Probably don't hijack this thread if you have a new question of your own; ask it as a separate question instead. Make sure you don't forget any of the verbs. (But this is probably covered in existing questions. Search before asking.)